# How does this CORS options callback function work?

Tags: node.js, cors

```
const whitelist = ['https://www.yoursite.com', 'http://127.0.0.1:5500', 'http://localhost: 3500'];

const corsOptions = {
   origin: (argOrigin, argCallbackFx)=>{
      if(whitelist.indexOf(argOrigin) !== -1)
         argCallbackFx(null, true);       
      else      
         argCallbackFx(new Error('From server.js: Blocked by CORS'));      
   },
   optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(errorHandler);
```

The callback function in the above code is actually getting called. I know this because the `errorHandler` function is actually writing the error statement passed to `argCallbackFx` in a log file.

Where is the callback getting called from? Who is calling it?
How is its text being passed to the `errorHandler`?

I am not explicitly calling that callback anywhere nor I am explicitly telling that `errorHandler` to receive the callback's value.

This is the body of `errorHandler`:

```
const { loggerFx } = require('./logger');
const errorHandler = (argErr, argRequest, argResponse, next)=>{
    loggerFx(`${argErr.name}: ${argErr.message}`, 'errorLog.txt');
    argResponse.status(500).send(argErr.message);
 }
 module.exports = errorHandler;
```

Comment: You're passing a callback to a library - _the library_ calls it back. As to how the value gets to the next middleware, presumably via `next()` - that's the point of middleware. The library's open source, have a look at [the code](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/f038e7722838fd83935674aa8c5bf452766741fb/lib/index.js#L219-L226) or use a debugger to step through it if you want more details.

Comment: I wouldn't feel bad about not understanding how to use this callback functionality. I don't find it intuitive myself; besides, I find it [dangerous](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#do-not-support-custom-callbacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is where is the callback getting called from? Who is calling it?

It is called by the middleware function returned by `cors(corsOptions)`. If you want to debug this, look at [this](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/f038e7722838fd83935674aa8c5bf452766741fb/lib/index.js#L219-L226) part of the `cors` source code. You register that middleware function with the statement

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

> How is its text being passed to the errorHandler?

This mechanism is explained [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). The callback function passes the `new Error('From server.js: Blocked by CORS')` to the `next` function ([here](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/f038e7722838fd83935674aa8c5bf452766741fb/lib/index.js#L221)) and the error handler receives it.

Comment: Thank you. What if I put some other middleware function in between, then will `next` be able to find the `errorHandler`?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl assuming the middleware is written correctly, of course. Again, that's the _point_ of middleware. Have a look at https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you. Great documentation link. Will read it